# Yii Jasphp Reporting Extension :: Usage

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I just installed  yii jasPHP extenstion for reporting my application. I need some guide or example to use more. I can send a string to pdf. But I need a complete table from database.

How can I do that... ? please help me out

## My Controller

```
public function actionReport()
{
    //$s = 'Welcome to review reports as well';
    $q = 'SELECT email FROM users where ID = 1';
    $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($q);
    $result = $cmd->queryScalar();

    Yii::app()->jasPHP->create(getcwd() . '/reports/', 'report1.jrxml', array('title' => $result,));
}
```

please let me know some examples.

Comment: Refer this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jasphp/). read comment sections.

Comment: I am not getting any solutions / examples from there. Could you please provide me some idea to do that ?

Comment: for reporting tool this is not working for large amount of reporting. I got a better solution for my application that is : Reportico php open source reporting tool. This is OK for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Here](https://github.com/cezario/yiijasper) you can get sample code. Happy Coding

Comment: @SelimReza: @ anytime